# Формула для поиска третьей вершины прямоугольного треугольника

Tags: perl, геометрия

Ребят. Не силен в математических преобразованиях. Может у кого есть готовая формула для поиска координаты третьей вершины (С) прямоугольного треугольника зная координаты двух других вершин (А и В). Так же известен катет АС и AB.

Из геометрии помню, что надо решать систему двух уравнений, но там черт ногу сломает... Может есть кого уже готовые формулы для нахождения x и y точки С?

Comment: У Вас вопрос звучит так: "Может есть кого уже готовые формулы для нахождения x и y точки С?", Вам дали на него ответ, если он является верным, пометьте его как принятый. Пояснение же "Смутно представляю как мне это в код вставить... :) Мне надо решить эту задачу в perl" является уже другим вопросом и поэтому стоит задать новый вопрос конкретно по реализации с примером Вашего кода.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну в общем-то всё просто.

1. Вектор `AB = B - A` покоординатно. Делим обе координаты на длину, получаем единичный вектор, пусть будет `v1`.
2. Поворачиваем вектор `v1` на 90 градусов, получаем вектор вдоль другого катета. Пусть будет результат `v2`. Поворот по простой формуле:

   ```
   v2.x = -v1.y;
   v2.y = v1.x;
   ```

   Альтернативно поворот в другую сторону:

   ```
   v2.x = v1.y;
   v2.y = -v1.x;
   ```
3. Имея единичный вектор `v2` вдоль второго катета, умножаем покоординатно на длину второго катета, получаем вектор `AC`.
4. Прибавляем к координатам `A` вектор `AC`, получаем точку `C`.

Будет два решения, для поворота по или против часовой стрелки.

Comment: Смутно представляю как мне это в код вставить... :) Мне надо решить эту задачу в perl

Comment: @GosuUndeadGhost: Ну это вы уж сами, я перла вовсе не знаю. Алгоритм у вас есть, он простой как доска. Программируйте.

Answer (score 3):

Рабочий код на С++ по правильному ответу:

```
    //0. Длина катета АВ (ab):
    //   ab = Sqrt((xa_− xb_)^2+(ya_− yb_)^2)
    //1. Вектор AB = B - A, покоординатно. Делим обе координаты на длину, получаем единичный вектор (v1):
    //   v1.x =  (B.x - A.x) / ab  ===  v1x = (xb_ - xa_) / ab
    //   v1.y =  (B.y - A.y) / ab  ===  v1y = (yb_ - ya_) / ab
    //2. Поворачиваем вектор v1 на 90 градусов, получаем вектор вдоль другого катета (v2). Поворот по формуле:
    //   v2.x = -v1.y              ===  v2x = -v1y
    //   v2.y =  v1.x              ===  v2y =  v1x
    //   Альтернативно поворот в другую сторону:
    //   v2.x =  v1.y;
    //   v2.y = -v1.x;
    //3. Имея единичный вектор v2 вдоль второго катета, умножаем покоординатно на длину второго катета, получаем вектор AC:
    //   v3.x = v2.x * bc_         ===  v3x = v2x * bc_
    //   v3.y = v2.y * bc_         ===  v3y = v2y * bc_
    //4. Прибавляем к координатам A вектор AC, получаем точку C:
    //   xc_ = xa_ + v3x
    //   yc_ = ya_ + v3y
    void __fastcall TriangleStraight3V_01(int xa_, int ya_, int xb_, int yb_, int bc_, int &xc_, int &yc_)
    {
      int      x2x1 = xa_ - xb_;
      int      y2y1 = ya_ - yb_;
      double   ab   = Sqrt(x2x1*x2x1 + y2y1*y2y1);
      double   v1x  = (xb_ - xa_) / ab;
      double   v1y  = (yb_ - ya_) / ab;
      double   v3x  = (v1y > 0 ? -v1y :  v1y) * bc_;
      double   v3y  = (v1x > 0 ?  v1x : -v1x) * bc_;

      xc_ = xa_ + v3x;
      yc_ = ya_ + v3y;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

[Моя имплементация на Паскале](https://github.com/gusenov/problem-solving-in-pascal/tree/master/ua/06-find-third-vertex-of-triangle) правильного ответа. Основная функция:

```
function FindPointB(T: Triangle; no: Integer): Point;
var
  unitVec: Point;
begin

  // Единичный вектор:
  unitVec.x := (T.pointA.x - T.pointC.x) / T.sideB;
  unitVec.y := (T.pointA.y - T.pointC.y) / T.sideB;

  if no = 1 then begin  // первое решение.
    Result.x := T.pointC.x + (-unitVec.y * T.sideA);
    Result.y := T.pointC.y + (unitVec.x * T.sideA);
  end else begin  // второе решение.
    Result.x := T.pointC.x + (unitVec.y * T.sideA);
    Result.y := T.pointC.y + (-unitVec.x * T.sideA);
  end;

end;
```

В данной постановке задача имеет два решения. На примере [египетского треугольника](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA):

[image: Два решения]

Блок-схема с формулами:

[image: Блок-схема]

Пример выполнения программы:

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 0):

Метод на C#

```
  PointF GetOrtogonalPoint(PointF a, PointF b, float bc)
    {
        float x2x1 = a.X - b.X;
        float y2y1 = a.Y - b.Y;
        float ab = (float)Math.Sqrt(x2x1 * x2x1 + y2y1 * y2y1);
        float v1x = (b.X - a.X) / ab;
        float v1y = (b.Y - a.Y) / ab;
        float v3x = (v1y > 0 ? -v1y : v1y) * bc;
        float v3y = (v1x > 0 ? v1x : -v1x) * bc;

        PointF c = new PointF();
        c.X = a.X + v3x;
        c.Y = a.Y + v3y;
        return c;
    }
```

Направление задаётся знаком bc.